# Don't you think minus rep could cause negative effect?

Tags: discussion, reputation, notification-bar, negative-rep

When you gain something, it means that you will lose it some days. That is indeed. However, there is 2 kinds of losing. Lost something without aware of it and vice versa. And I believe that when we know we've lost something, it will cause a great discouragement for us.

No hard feeling about this, I've joined the Stack for quite few years (I lost my old one, this is my new account). I know how to ask questions, how to answer it, and how to accept the fact of losing rep. But it's not like everyone, such as newbie, could understand this.

What I am trying to say is to announce users that they have just lost reputation isn't a good idea. I understand that we should record it for transparent purpose. Imagine what happen when we're announced that we've lost rep because this or that, more or less, disappointed feeling is something hard to avoid. This especially true for newbie, who need a good support and encouragement to join the community.

Generally, Stack communities are built on the good purposes. But keep treating each other 'equally' as machine isn't a good idea. Not at all.

Comment: We don't announce to users that they've lost rep; the achievement notification only shows up on positive rep changes.

Comment: Or are you suggesting the people shouldn't be told at all that they've lost rep? That would just lead to "why have I lost rep" questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as unclear because I'm not clear on what it's actually seeing as a problem or requesting: The concept of rep loss? The concept of notifying people about rep loss, even though that doesn't exist? Users ever being able to find out they lost rep and why? Something else?

Comment: to be fair, as @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog said, silently hiding negative rep changes - probably hoping that "the user won't notice and thus won't go around crying and creating more moderation work" - has been a policy over the network for quite a long time now. That said, I must also add that as far as I am concerned, this whole idea is wrong - hiding info to the end user because we assume it will create more work (because we also assume that the user will cry because of it) doesn't feel really considerate nor kind.

Answer (score 3):

No and on the contrary, reputation reduction has a positive effect in the context of the site.

If my reputation drops, I'm alerted to that fact and it compels me to fix whatever I suspect caused that drop. Sometimes voters even help you out with a comment. We're building Q & A sites, and reputation loss is a helpful mechanism for peer-review.

A negative reputation score on a question also helps you in judging whether or not you should answer the question.

Reputation movements in either direction should never be taken personally.

(On Meta, reputation works slightly differently - if this answer goes negative then it's more of a matter that this is not the typical community view rather than anything else. Certainly, don't take reputation movements personally here.)